# Fast evaluation of a function in many points

Tags: performance-tuning, evaluation, numerics, parallelization

I need to feed to an external program a number of points (in `Complex128` format) generated from the numerical evaluation of some function, e.g. $e^{i \vec{k}\cdot\vec{x}}$. The function is evaluated at points of some evenly spaced grid. I currently generate the values with `Table` (possibly multidimensional, and then `Flatten`'d) and send it to a file with `BinaryWrite`. However, this is rather slow, because I use a number of points in the order of $2^{24}$ or more. I tried with `ParallelTable`, but I inspected with `perf` and it appears that when transferring the data to the main kernel there's a lot of UTF string encoding going on for whatever reason, which defeats the speedup in the parallelization.

Is there any smarter way to accomplish what I need?

Comment: I think you need to be more specific. What are the values? Are the values you generate a function of, say, the position in the (multidimensional) table?

Comment: Taking the example in the question, I need to generate the values of $e^{ikx}$ for a fixed $k$ and for $x = 0, .., 100$. I clarified in the question that the function is evaluated on some grid.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In cases like this where the function to be evaluated a) has the `Listable` attribute, and b) is not very compicated, we can get a huge benefit from exploiting this listability. In my experience, exploiting vectorized operations, listability and packed arrays, along with occational compilation to C, usually has a much larger impact on speed than parallellizing.

**One dimension**

For `k = 2.5` and $2^{24}$ points:

```
First@AbsoluteTiming[ans1 = Exp[I*2.5*Range[2^24]]];
(* 1.270682 *)

First@AbsoluteTiming[ans2 = Table[Exp[I*2.5*x], {x, 2^24}]];
(* 19.620243 *)

First@AbsoluteTiming[ans3 = Exp /@ (I*2.5*Range[2^24])];
(* 3.358687 *)

ans1 == ans2 == ans3
(* True *)
```

Note that the last one uses the `Listable` attribute of `Times`, but not of `Exp`. On my machine it's still way faster than `Table` though.

**Three dimensions**

Since $e^{a+b} = e^a e^b$ we can still do most of the calculation vectorized. Note that we don't need a square grid. For $\vec{k} = \{k_x, k_y, k_z\} = \{2.5, 3.5, 4.5\}$:

```
(* using Table *)
First@AbsoluteTiming[
  ans1 = Table[Exp[I (k1 x + k2 y + k3 z)]
  , {x, 100}, {y, 101}, {z, 102}];
]
(* 1.979192 *)

(* using Table, but vectorizing over one coordinate *)
First@AbsoluteTiming[
  ans2 = Table[Exp[I (k1 x + k2 y + k3 Range[102])]
  , {x, 100}, {y, 101}];
]
(* 0.225951 *)

(* My favorite *)
First@AbsoluteTiming[
  x = Exp[I k1 Range[100]];
  y = Exp[I k2 Range[101]]; 
  z = Exp[I k3 Range[102]];
  ans3 = Outer[Times, x, y, z];
]
(* 0.028202 *)
```

They are equal up to roundoff:

```
Chop[ans1 - ans2] == Chop[ans1 - ans3] == ConstantArray[0, {100, 101, 102}]
(* True *)
```

**More complicated example**

When the function to be evaluated is not easily split into parts that depend only on one component, I usually check [this list](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/1096/list-of-compilable-functions) to see if it can be compiled. If for instance the function is

```
f[x_, y_, z_] := Sin[2x + Exp[I(x + y*z)]]
```

we find:

```
First@AbsoluteTiming[ans1 = Table[f[x, y, z], {x, 100}, {y, 101}, {z, 102}];]
(* 4.599261 *)

First@AbsoluteTiming[ans2 = Outer[f, Range[100], Range[101], Range[102]];]
(* 3.056824 *)

(* We can still vectorize over one coordinate *)
First@AbsoluteTiming[ans3 = Table[f[x, y, Range[102]], {x, 100}, {y, 101}];]
(* 1.463473 *)
```

But here, a compiled function is much faster:

```
comp = Compile[{},
  Table[Sin[2 x + Exp[I (x + y*z)]]
  ,{x, 100}, {y, 101}, {z, 102}], 
  CompilationTarget -> "C", RuntimeOptions -> "Speed"
];
First@AbsoluteTiming[ans4 = comp[];]
(* 0.145347 *)
```

Comment: Oddly enough the Fourier transform can be competitive until `n` is quite large. Only applies if the grid divides the unit circle into equal segments though. A modification of the example above should show what I mean. `In[501]:= n = 25;
ivec = UnitVector[2^n, 2];
Timing[ans1 = Fourier[ivec];]
AbsoluteTiming[
 ans2 = Exp[2.*Pi*I*Range[0, 2^n - 1]/2.^n]/Sqrt[2.^n];]
Max[Abs[ans1 - ans2]]

Out[503]= {2.229677, Null}

Out[504]= {1.564221, Null}

Out[505]= 1.53329341668*10^-19`

Comment: I get the gist of it. However I'm thinking how this could be extended to the vector case (or in other words when the function depends on multiple variables).

Comment: Very thorough, thanks.

Comment: Impressive usage of `Outer`