# Fast Evaluation of a series of dot product

Tags: performance-tuning, numerics, evaluation, parallelization

**Context**

I have a function that depends on 3 real variables x,y and z and that is defined by a series of matrix products. The evaluation of f for a specific (x,y,z) is fast ~0.02 sec but I want to evaluate the function on a huge number of points (a regularly spaced grid of x,y and z values) which in the end makes the evaluation really slow if not unmanageable. I have already tried what was proposed in [this answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/101696/fast-evaluation-of-a-function-in-many-points), but my function is not compilable, and ParalellTable is faster that vectorizing on my laptop.

**Illustration**

For the sake of simplicity let me illustrate this with

```
weight = RandomReal[1, 200];
pts = RandomReal[1, 200];
M = RandomReal[1, {200, 200}];
f[x_,y_] = (weight*Exp[-pts*x]).Exp[M].(weight*Exp[-pts*y])//N
```

How would one make the evaluation of f on multiple couples of (x,y) faster than relying on ParallelTable ?

```
ans = ParallelTable[f[x,y],{x,Range[100]},{y,Range[100]}]
```

Thanks a lot for your help!

Comment: I recommend considering [CudaDot](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/CUDALink/ref/CUDADot.html), see e,g. [this example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8638905/would-a-better-graphics-card-or-more-cores-make-mathematica-faster/8639021#8639021)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

First of all, it helps a great deal to define `f` as follows:

```
ClearAll[f]
A = Exp[M];
f[x_, y_] := (weight*Exp[-pts*x]).A.(weight*Exp[-pts*y]);
```

Here, using `SetDelayed` (`:=`) is better than `Set` (`=`), because the latter creates a humongous symbolic expression that is very expensive to numericise. Defining `A` first ensures that `Exp[M]` is computed only once.

```
First@AbsoluteTiming[
  ClearAll[f];
  A = Exp[M];
  f[x_, y_] := (weight*Exp[-pts*x]).A.(weight*Exp[-pts*y]);
  ans = ParallelTable[f[x, y], {x, 1., 100}, {y, 1., 100}];
  ]
```

> 0.098479

Still, for each `x` the vector `(weight*Exp[-pts*x])` is computed 100 times -- unless the JIT compiler does something clever. This can be mended as follows:

```
First@AbsoluteTiming[
  A = Exp[M];
  X = Table[weight Exp[-x pts], {x, 1., 100.}];
  Y = Table[weight Exp[-y pts], {y, 1., 100.}];
  ans2 = Block[{u},
    ParallelTable[
     u = X[[i]].A;
     Table[u.Y[[j]], {j, 1, 100}]
     , {i, 1, 100}]
    ];
  ]
```

> 0.038625

Moreover, we can fuse all the $2 \times 100 \times 100 = 20000$ `Dot` operations in the `ParallelTable` into two matrix-matrix `Dots`. This does not reduce the number of flops, but it reduces the calling overhead and allows the `Dot` routine to exploit horizontal vectorization and cache friendly task decomposition.

```
First@AbsoluteTiming[
  A = Exp[M];
  U = Exp[-KroneckerProduct[Range[1., 100.], pts]].DiagonalMatrix[
     SparseArray[weight ]];
  V = weight Exp[-KroneckerProduct[pts, Range[1., 100.]]];
  ans3 = U.A.V;
  ]
```

> 0.000677

This is about $200000$ times faster than the original code.

Just to check the relative errors:

```
Max[Abs[ans/ans2 - 1]]
Max[Abs[ans/ans3 - 1]]
```

> 1.11022*10^-16
>
> 1.77636*10^-15

Comment: Thanks a lot ! This is indeed much smarter than what I was doing :)

Comment: You're welcome.